# Adding prefix to value depending on length of value by conditional formatting Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I want to fill cells by numbers which may have various length (common is 4 or 5), then i wanna to add number prefix depending on length of value by conditional formatting
e.g. 1111 (length is 4) should be formated to "20001111" (adding prefix 2000) and e.g. 11111 (length is 5) should be formated to "20011111".
So difference is just how many additional "0" will be added by conditional formatting.
How can i do this?
I know that i can use conditional statements in formulas and i've tried it already. I couldnt find how can i get value length and how can i use it in conditional statements.

Comment: You don't need conditional formatting, but just a custom number formatting. Select your range and use `20000000` and it should format your numbers as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the formula you need:  `=LEFT("20000000",8-LEN(A1))&A1`

Please analyze this to learn more about formulas.

[image]

Comment: You are welcome.  BTW, Conditional formatting is something different, you can search for it.  On the other hand, this problem can also be solved with conditional statements like `IF` but this one is a way better solution.

Comment: Yes, my fault, i thought it can work like a scripts or something.

Comment: It could be better if it possible to make automated modification of cell when u set the value without using additional cell with source

Comment: I know it is possible on Google Sheets with Apps Script, but im afraid in Excel it can be realised only with VB...